# How to handle RewriteRules when the word has similar first characters?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been trying to figure it out for a hours now, yet, always one of my redirects does not work. I have path `something.com/blog/article-name` and `something.com/blogujeme` to act as a article list. But I cannot get those two redirects to work, since they share the same first characters and regex fails me. So far what I came up with is:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!blog\?)(blogujeme)$ blog/category-view.php
RewriteRule ^(?!blogujeme\?)(blog) blog/page-view.php
```

The first rewrite rule actually works, but the second does not and redirects to  `something.com/blog` instead of `something.com/blogujeme`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, but that hardly solves my problem, the redirects still do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I cannot get to work those two redirects, since they share same
>   first characters and regex fails me

You should **not** have any problem like this with a regular expression, since your 2 examples can be differentiated. Actually, your issue is about *mod_rewrite* rules syntax/semantic.

Here is what you need to write in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder in this case)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # prevent from infinite loop
RewriteRule ^blog/.+$ blog/page-view.php [L]

RewriteRule ^blogujeme$ blog/category-view.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, misclick on the downvote and didn't realize until it was locked in.

Comment: This is the most correct and thorough answer, awarded the bounty

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions and a few Apache `mod_rewrite` directives to achieve what you want. You'll have to use a condition to check if the request is a file and if it is, then process the file rather than continue with the rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/.*$ blog/page-view.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blogujeme$ blog/category-view.php [L]
```

Then you'll have:

```
/blog -> blog/page-view.php
/blogujeme -> blog/category-view.php
/blog/page-view.php -> blog/page-view.php
/blog/category-view.php -> blog/category-view.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Shooting from the hip - how about a word boundary anchor?

```
RewriteRule \bblogujeme$ blog/category-view.php
RewriteRule \bblog\b.* blog/page-view.php
```

Comment: Did not work, same result. It really gives me a lot of pains. Simplest may to use completely different words for those two pages, but maybe someone will come up with something

Comment: I'm not familiar with URL rewrites, but it seems to me your start and end anchors (the `^` and `$`) aren't correct. Try the modified regex. (Doing some googling I looks like it depends on the `RewriteBase` - correct? Maybe there *should* be a start anchor (`^`) instead of the slash `\/`...)

Comment: Testing on [this site](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) it appears that `RewriteRule \bblogujeme$  blog/category-view.php` and `RewriteRule \bblog\b.* blog/page-view.php` might do it for you. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer to "what are you doing wrong" is not to use [L] as an indicator to mod_rewrite to STOP and be satisfied when it has hit a match.

Order your "similar" regular expressions in an order where the most specific one goes first. If that hits and has a [L] in the end, then no more rules will run.

If it doesn't hit, the next one will be tried. Thus they can be seen as
"if, else if, etc.."